# Missing methods in PySpark 2.4's pyspark.sql.functions but still works in local environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark2.4.4

I'm using PySpark 2.4 and I noticed that the pyspark.sql.functions module is missing some methods like trim and col. In PyCharm, it shows as undefined. However, I have written some tasks using these methods and they run correctly in the local environment of PySpark 2.4, with the expected results. Why is that?

Here is my environment setup:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def create_env():
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("HiveTest") \
        .master("local") \
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://master:9083") \
        .config("spark.hadoop.hive.exec.scratchdir", "/user/hive/tmp") \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    return spark
```

And here is an excerpt of my SparkSQL code:

```py
df = spark.table("ods.t_ctp20_department_d").select(
    trim(col("departmentid")).alias("branch_id"),
    trim(col("departmentid")).alias("branch_no"),
    trim(col("departmentname")).alias("branch_name"),
    when(trim(col("departmentid")) == 'FU', '00')
    .when(length(trim(col("departmentid"))) == 2, 'FU')
    .when(length(trim(col("departmentid"))) == 4, substring(trim(col("departmentid")), 1, 2))
    .when(length(trim(col("departmentid"))) == 6, substring(trim(col("departmentid")), 1, 4))
    .otherwise(substring(trim(col("departmentid")), 1, 6)).alias("up_branch_no"),
    lit('0').alias("branch_type"),
    lit('00').alias("data_source"),
    col("brokerid").alias("brokers_id"),
    lit(busi_date).alias("ds_date")
)
```

I tried using the trim and col methods from the pyspark.sql.functions module in my PySpark 2.4 code.
Surprisingly, even though my PyCharm IDE highlighted these methods as undefined, my code still executed successfully in the local PySpark 2.4 environment and produced the expected results.

I have a Python script that I run either by executing "python3 xx.python" or by using a remote interpreter in PyCharm. The remote interpreter is set up with only the pyspark2.4 package installed within a virtual environment.

When running the script in PyCharm, everything seems to run fine. However, I encounter an error stating that the function is not defined when accessing the pyspark2.4 API.

I would like to understand the reason behind this error. Is there any additional configuration required in PyCharm when using pyspark2.4? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: see spark function list. the functions in question were introduced in the initial versions. I guess pycharm needs to be configured correctly.

Comment: Did you try to include them `from pyspark.sql.functions import trim, col`? If so there is a possibility that you might be able to access trim only via `expr` like this `expr("trim(your_var)")`

Comment: Using the format expr("trim(your_var)") is not a good idea, because you may need to use other functions besides trim, and it also lacks hints. Is there a better way? (Of course I have correctly imported functions.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `col`, `lit` and some other functions [are binded dynamically](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L259). This goes back to the very early versions of Spark, and looks like it comes to handle versions compatibility.

Comment: However, I checked the source code of pyspark.sql.functions in pyspark2.4, and the trim function is missing. This leads to PyCharm not being able to suggest the existence of trim.

Additionally, I am sure that I have correctly imported pyspark.sql.functions.

Could you please tell me how to solve the problem that it is not suggested during development, although it can run correctly after writing?

Comment: There is no problem to be solved. These functions are not **statically** part of pyspark.sql.functions - they get bind to pyspark.sql.functions only on **runtime**. There is nothing (I know of) that you can do to make your IDE recognize them as park of the `functions` module.

Answer (score 0):

I run the following commands in the interpreter to enable IDE to support different versions of the API, and it seems to work with both 2.4 and 3.2 source code prompts:

```bash
pip install pyspark==2.4.0 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
pip install pyspark==3.2.0 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
pip install pyspark==2.4.0 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

It seems that the removal of version 3.2 was not clean and actually allows the IDE to support features from both versions. If anyone has encountered a similar issue, you can try this approach.